# SQL: All category into a single columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I need i query that return me a record with a columns "category" that show me all category for a single article.

For Example: I have an article , i would like to know all category to which that item belongs in a single Colums separated by a comma, how can i do that?

[image]

Comment: Please add the schema of your table and an example of the result you wish to receive.

Comment: Are you saying you have a data structure like |Article|Category1,Category3|?

Comment: @Seojudo, please look into using MySQL's `GROUP_CONCAT()` aggregate function.

Comment: @MichaelBissell no! My Db respect the RelationationShip system , obviously

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `GROUP_CONCAT` ... example:

```
SELECT article, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT category ORDER BY category) AS categories
FROM articles
group by article
ORDER BY article;
```

Comment: I just finished to testing it and works great! Exactly what I was looking--happy new Year!